# Pagination in Javafx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-11

I am having problem on viewing two tabs on two different pages. I have two tabs called `sgp = new SetupGamePane();` and
`orp = new OverviewResultPane();`. These are both different class on rooted in root class and implemented pagination view system. When I run the program i can see only `orp = new OverviewResultPane();` page on both page. How can I apply sgp on 1st and orpon secong page. See below code.

```java
package view;

import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;

public class DiceGameRootPane extends Pagination {

    private SetupGamePane sgp;
    private OverviewResultPane orp;
    private Pagination p1, p2;


    public DiceGameRootPane() {

        this.setPageCount(2);
        this.setCurrentPageIndex(0);
        this.setStyle("-fx-border-color : blue");

        sgp = new SetupGamePane();
        orp = new OverviewResultPane();

        Pagination p1 = new Pagination(0);
        this.setPageFactory(e -> getSetupGamePane());

        Pagination p2 = new Pagination(1);
        this.setPageFactory(e -> getOverviewResultsPane());

        this.getChildren().addAll(p1, p2);

    }

    public SetupGamePane getSetupGamePane() {
        return  sgp;
    }

    public OverviewResultPane getOverviewResultsPane() {
        return orp;
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Call `setPageFactory` only once.  Change `e ->` to `pageNum ->`.  Does that clarify the rest of what you need to do?